# Joomla Not making databases

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have Joomla Stable Pack 2.5.4. I Installed it to localhost(wamp server). But it only displays the progress wheel when installing but nothing happens. But it not creates databases and tables. My connection settings are correct. I don't know where's the problem. When I installing Joomla new version it works. What's the problem here?
Sorry for my english. Please help

Comment: Is the SQL user has permission to create database and tables?

Comment: This is a golden example of when logs are a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is most likely a permissions issue. In PHPmyAdmin, give the database user create permissions that that the tables can be created upon installation.

If this has already been done, then open the **php.ini** file and increase the *memory limit* to 128mb, and *execute time* to 3000 seconds as shown below:

```
max_execution_time = 3000 ;
memory_limit=128M ;
```

Also, ensure you're using PHP 5.3 or 5.4 as I believe there will be issues on Joomla 2.5 with PHP 5.5

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! But I don't know how to edit the php.ini file. Where's it?

Comment: Left click on the wamp icon on your taskbar, hover over the PHP tab, then click *php.ini*

Answer (score 0):

If its a Quickstart Package or a Bundled Package make sure you have mysqli extension on your wamp or rather I would suggest you use XAMPP which comes effectively built more than WAMP.